# Некорректное отображение товаров

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что некорректно отображаются товары, некие дыры в списке. Как починить? Кто-то сталкивался с таким? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это проблема не в opencart, а с вёрсткой.

Comment: Как я понял блоки товаров у вас сделаны через `float: left` попробуйте заменить на `display: inline-block`

Comment: первые два блока в верхнем ряду выше следующих двух. соответственно, их нижние границы располагаются ниже. Следующие блоки упираются в их торчащие краешки - это float так работает. Задайте всем блокам одинаковую высоту или верстайте без float'ов.

Comment: Да, именно из-за звезд выше становятся... спасибо